# Не работает сортировка ORDER BY

Tags: sql, mysqli

Не понимаю почему не работает такая сортировка:

```
SELECT * FROM `dialogs` ORDER BY `date` DESC, `read` DESC
```

Пытаюсь сделать так:

Если read = 1 - Это значит, сообщение не прочитано.
Если read = 0 - Прочитано.
Date это - Дата диалога.

Так вот нужно сделать так, если есть не прочитанные диалоги то они выводятся первыми, и сортируются по дате.

Если диалог прочитан он должен идти после не прочитанных, и сортироваться по дате. Пробовал по разному, искал в инете, ничего не смог найти. Кто то может помочь как мне составить запрос что бы он работал как я хочу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А это запрос как работает?

Comment: @Эникейщик добавил скрин. Красным - это не прочитанные, они должны быть в верху, но они сортируются просто по дате.

Comment: Вот [тут может быть решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066453/mysql-group-by-and-order-by).

Comment: @Эникейщик вроде бы допёр, нужно местами поменять, сначала read а потом date, так как запрос составляется последовательно)

Comment: поменяйте местами, что первым что вторым

Comment: Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы до публикации вопроса.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM `dialogs` ORDER BY `read` DESC, `date` DESC
```

Нужно было поменять местами, что бы сначала сортировался по `read` а потом по `date`.